Log Compaction and Key Selection in Kafka
I'm trying to understand key selection in Kafka and am hoping for some clarification. Supposing I have an IoT solution that sends events into Kafka with the following schema:
{
  "home_id": "SOME_UUID",
  "device_id": "SOME_UUID",
  "event_id": "SOME_UUID",
  "event_value": 1234
}

I plan to run analytics on this data, and it is important that I receive events in the order they are sent within a home_id. This forum post makes me think that I should then use home_id as the key. However, The ksqlDB reference on Tables has made me concerned that log compaction will remove older events that share the same key.
Am I right in viewing the key as the field that will determine the uniqueness of an event when Kafka decides to clean up events that are "no longer necessary"? Is there a way I can guarantee both ordering within a home_id and the retention of unique event_ids?
